# Identifying file causing hang from strace

Tags: memory, gtk, ubuntu-10.04, strace

I have a GTK program running on Ubuntu 10.04 that hangs in interruptible state, and I'd like to understand the output of `strace`. In particular, I have this line:

```
read(5, 0x2ba9ac4, 4096) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

I suspect `5` is the file descriptor, `0x2ba9ac4` the address in this file to be read, and `4096` the amount of data to read. Can you confirm? More importantly, how can one determine which file the program is trying to read? This file descriptor does not exist in `/proc/pid/fd` (which is probably why the program hangs).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find which file uses this file descriptor by calling `strace -o log -eopen,read yourprogram`. Then search in the `log` file the call to `read` of interest. From this line (and not from the first line of the file), search upwards the first occurrence of this file descriptor (returned by a call to `open`).

For example here, the file descriptor returned by `open` is 3:

```
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
```

Comment: this pointed to `/etc/passwd`... can I be sure that it is correct, i.e., is there a chance that the file descriptor is modified in between by another function than `open`? thanks

Comment: If it's the first `open` with this file descriptor above the faulty `read`, then yes, the file is that one. The file descriptor can be reused only if `close` has been called on it. If you want to be sure, use `-eopen,read,close`. A file descriptor is associated uniquely to a file between the corresponding `open` and `close`.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `read()` is simply the destination pointer, it's asking for a read from file descriptor 5, and max 4096 bytes. See [the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) for `read()`.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out, is there any way to identify the file associated to the file descriptor 5?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @liberforce answer, if the process is already running you can get the file name using lsof

form strace

```
[pid  7529] read(102, 0x7fedc64c2fd0, 16) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Now, with lsof

```
lsof -p 7529 | grep 102
java    7529 luis  102u  0000                0,9        0     9178 anon_inode
```